# React - Issue rendering component nested within a function

Tags: reactjs, rendering

I am a super newbie to React / JS / coding.
I am building a page where books are put on shelves based on their reading status. So one shelf for books currently being read, a second one for book I want to read, etc.

At the moment, the only thing that is rendering is the name of the shelves. For some reason, the code within return() of the shelf function does not render.
The code does get executed until that point. When I `console.log(book.author)` I do get what I want, but then within `return(<p>{book.author}</p>` it does not get rendered.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks a lot for your help!

```
import React from 'react';
import Book from './Book'

const shelf = (props, chosenStatus) => {
    props.books.filter(book => book.status === chosenStatus).map( book => { 
        console.log(book.author);
        return(
            <div>
                <p>{book.author}</p>
                <Book 
                    author = {book.author}
                    title = {book.title}
                    status = {book.status}
                />
            </div>
            
        )
    })   
} 

const shelves = (props) => {
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Reading</h1>
            {shelf(props, 'Reading')}
            <h1>Wanna read</h1>
            {shelf(props, 'Wanna read')}
            <h1>Read</h1>
            {shelf(props, 'Read')}
        </div>
    );
}

 export default shelves
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `shelf` code doesn't render is because you didn't return the filtered array of react jsx in `shelf` function. Just replace {} with () brackets.

```
import React from 'react';
import Book from './Book'

const shelf = (props, chosenStatus) => (
    props.books.filter(book => book.status === chosenStatus).map( book => { 
        console.log(book.author);
        return(
            <div>
                <p>{book.author}</p>
                <Book 
                    author = {book.author}
                    title = {book.title}
                    status = {book.status}
                />
            </div>
            
        )
    })   
) 

const shelves = (props) => {
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Reading</h1>
            {shelf(props, 'Reading')}
            <h1>Wanna read</h1>
            {shelf(props, 'Wanna read')}
            <h1>Read</h1>
            {shelf(props, 'Read')}
        </div>
    );
}

 export default shelves
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import Book from './Book'

const shelf = (props, chosenStatus) => {
    // Add a return here
    return props.books.filter(book => book.status === chosenStatus).map( book => { 
        console.log(book.author);
        return(
            <div>
                <p>{book.author}</p>
                <Book 
                    author = {book.author}
                    title = {book.title}
                    status = {book.status}
                />
            </div>
            
        )
    })   
} 

const shelves = (props) => {
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Reading</h1>
            {shelf(props, 'Reading')}
            <h1>Wanna read</h1>
            {shelf(props, 'Wanna read')}
            <h1>Read</h1>
            {shelf(props, 'Read')}
        </div>
    );
}

 export default shelves
```